# Multiple random varialbles

Tags: integration, probability-theory

$$f_X(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \begin{cases}
         \frac{1}{x_1x_2} &  0\leq x_3  \leq x_2 \leq x_1 \leq 1;\\[8pt]
        0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}  $$

question: Are $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are independent random variables.

to prove independence I have find individual distribution  of random variable in term of other two random variables.

But how to calculate it .How to put limits if I am calculation $f_{x_1}(x_1)$

Comment: If the random variables are independent, that means their joint distribution is the product of the marginal distributions. And marginal distribution of $x_1$, say, is calculated by integrating out the other two RVs.

Comment: @KevinC : I've always found that a misleading way of putting it.  Suppose $F_{X_1}$ and $F_{X_2}$ are the c.d.f.s of random variables $X_1$ and $X_1$, and $F_{X_2}(x)=F_{X_1}(x)=\left.\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }x<0, \\  x & \text{if }0\le x\le1, \\  1 & \text{if }x>1. \end{cases}\right\}$  Then by a commonplace definition, the product of those two functions is $F_{X_1}(x)F_{X_1}(x)=x^2$ if $0\le x\le1$.  But that's not what you must have intended.

Comment: *to prove independence I have find individual distribution of random variable*... Untrue. *in term of other two random variables*... Sorry but what do you mean by that?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Sorry but perhaps I'm not seeing the misleading part. What's wrong with $F_{X_1}(x)F_{X_2}(y)=xy$ for $x,y\in[0,1]$? Wouldn't $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent if their joint c.d.f $F_{X_1,X_2}(x,y)=xy$ for all $x,y\in[0,1]$? BTW, my training in probability theory is not as rigorous as I'd like, so I'd appreciate if you could point out any blind spot in my understanding.

Comment: Read carefully.  I wrote both as functions of $x$ rather than the two as functions of different variables, and the point is that the usual meaning of the concept of the product of two functions is consistent with that.

Answer (score 0):

The mere fact that $x_2$ is constrained to be less than $x_1$ tells you that they're not independent.

(And you shouldn't be calling the random variables by the same names as the arguments to the density function.  If you write $f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)$, using capital letters for the random variables and lower-case letters for the arguments, then you can make sense of such expressions as $f_{X_1,X_2}(0.8,0.3)$ or $\Pr(X_1 < x_1)$.)